# Can't train OpenCV CascadeClassifier to detect company logo

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm trying to train CascadeClassifier from OpenCV to detect a simple high-contrast company logo, but it doesn't work. What it detects looks like just random image patches. It doesn't even work on the original sample. I'm using opencv_createsamples to create a set of positives on a plain white background from a single original logo image.

At the same time I was able to successfully train a cascade for detecting stamps using many samples from real documents. This looks strange to me, because a stamp is much more complex than company logo.

What can I be doing wrong? Can LBP or Haar features be used do describe a simple object such as logo?

Comment: is it necessary that you need cascade classifier for this? isn't just template matching or feature descriptors like SIFT, SURF etc sufficient?

Comment: I'm trying both approaches, but SIFT matching seems much slower than a cascade classifier.

Answer (score 0):

It depending on the type of company logo and the accuraty level. LBP is very fast in training data, but less accurate than Haar classifier. Haar classiefier can take a week to learn the recognition, but is very accurate. To have a good classifier you need to have a lot of data. I don't know what data you have and how mutch. So I see that the question is asked long time ago...